# Count files and folders inside a certain directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to code a batch file that will count how many files and how many directories there are in current directory.

```
for /r %%i in (dir) do (
    if exist %%i\* (
        set /a directories=directories+1
    ) else (
        set /a files=files+1
    )
)
echo directories
echo files
```

This is the structure of a directory where I try to run this batch file:

```
---directory
   ---file1
---file2
```

And this always returns "2 files" and "0 directories".

Comment: Do you want to include files and direcotries in sub-directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set total=0
set dir=0
set files=0
for /f %a in ('dir /b') do (set /a total+=1)
for /f %a in ('dir /b /a:d') do (set /a dir+=1)
set /a files=%total%-%dir%

Echo There are %dir% direcotries and %files% files in the current directory alone
```

This will not count for sub-directories as well, you would use `for /r` and `for /r /d` for that.

Hope this helped, Mona.

Answer (score 0):

`for /r` will recursively search a directory (by default it will search the current directory) - `*` will return all files in the directory tree and `.` will return all directories in the tree.

```
@echo off

set files=
set directories=

for /r %%a in (*) do set /a files+=1
for /r %%b in (.) do set /a directories+=1

echo files:     %files%
echo directories:   %directories%
```

Take a look at the for command help page -

```
h:\>for /?

FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

    Walks the directory tree rooted at [drive:]path, executing the FOR
    statement in each directory of the tree.  If no directory
    specification is specified after /R then the current directory is
    assumed.  If set is just a single period (.) character then it
    will just enumerate the directory tree.
```

Comment: I am not sure if the he wants directories in sub-folders, since he has avoided mentioning it.

Comment: @Monacraft, I assumed he did want sub-directories, since he is gathering 'sub-files' (couldn't think of a better word there).